# sp_send_dbmail Column Header Format Issue (Incorrect syntax near '@Column1Name')

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, t-sql, stored-procedures

I keep getting an "Incorrect syntax near '+' error when trying to concatenate the column header. I'm trying to follow the tutorial below:

https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2014/04/excel-doesnt-open-csv-files-correctly-from-sp_send_dbmail/

```
DECLARE @tab char(1) = CHAR(9)
DECLARE @Column1Name VARCHAR(255)
SET @Column1Name = '[sep=,' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Date]'


EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@recipients = 'test@gmail.com',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_attachment_filename='test.csv',
@query_result_separator=@tab,
@query_result_no_padding=1,

@body = 'See attached file',

@subject = 'Testing Data',
@query = '(SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(20), Date, 20) AS' + @Column1Name + ', 
           Column2 FROM testTable)'
```

[image]

Comment: Put a space after `AS`. And you cannot provide an expression for a stored procedure parameter, you need to pre-calculate it.

Comment: Thank you! I added the space however, I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't supply expressions as parameters when executing stored procedures.

Set the full result to a variable first, then simply pass that variable as the parameter:

```
DECLARE @tab char(1) = CHAR(9)
DECLARE @Column1Name VARCHAR(255)
SET @Column1Name = '[sep=,' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Date]'

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX) = '(SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(20), Date, 20) AS' + @Column1Name + ', Column2 FROM testTable)'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @recipients = 'test@gmail.com',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
    @query_attachment_filename='test.csv',
    @query_result_separator=@tab,
    @query_result_no_padding=1,
    @body = 'See attached file',
    @subject = 'Testing Data',
    @query = @query
```

---

**PD:** You might want to check if you need to add a space between concatenations when building dynamic SQL. In this case ***it's not needed*** as you already have the square brackets, but might as well get used to adding spaces.

```
 ... '20) AS ' + @Column1Name + ' , Column2 FROM testTable)'
```

Comment: Thank you! I added the space however, I'm still getting the same error

Comment: The space is not the solution, the first part is (not supplying an expression directly on the SP call).

Comment: You are correct! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You might need to add an extra space in.
Currently it will resolve to *CONVERT(CHAR(20), Date, 20) AS@Column1Name*